# Searching dynamic Label.IDs to match Query result

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I am currently dynamically generating labels ids on my ASP site based on the date of the month.

E.g. labelSunday1.ID = "01/07/12"

I am also pulling data down from SQL Server, and storing various values in strings.
E.g. Date = resultDate, stock = resultStock

However, I want to do a find on the page, looking for any Label ID that matches the result of the query, and then display the number of stock in the labels text.

Is there anyway I can search the entire page to see if a label ID matches the resultDate string? I would rather do this search somewhat dynamically, as in the future I hope to dynamically generate many labels on the page.

I was thinking along the lines of:

```
IF Me.Label.ID = resultDate then
me.label.text = resultStock
```

but that doesn't work :C

Thanks in advance

Comment: ID's can only be alphanumeric (+ underscore **_**). For example: `Label_1234`

Comment: Ah, bums. So no date slashes?

Comment: No, but an ID is just what it is, an identifier. Nothing what you should use for additional informations like a date. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: you can still have date like this : **01_07_12**

Comment: Basically,  calender effect that will be able to modify the stock. However at the moment I am displaying a single calender, but the page itself will eventually display the current month's calender, and the future 11 month's calenders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use "01_01_2013" as an Identifier.